# sorl-thumnail resizing and saving

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm trying to use sorl-thumnail to resize the image in the views then saving it and getting IOError while calling get_thumnail(). Also I need to know how to save the resized image. Sorry if you consider this silly..I'm new to Django.

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class BasicModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob = models.DateField()
    photo = ImageField(upload_to='sample')

class BasicModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = BasicModel
```

Views.py:

```
def BasicView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = BasicModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                    im = get_thumbnail(request.FILES['photo'], '100x100', crop='center', quality=99)
                    data = form.save()
                    return preview(request, data.id, im)
    else:
            form = BasicModelForm()
    return render_to_response("unnamed.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def preview(request, id, im):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BasicModel, pk=id)
    return render_to_response("preview.html", {'obj': obj, 'im': im})
```

preview.html:

```
{{ obj.name }}
{{ obj.dob }}
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail im "100x100" as image %}
<img src="{{ image.url }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nirmal/try/files/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/files/'
```

Errors:

```
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/nirmal/try/files/wp.jpg'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py in _open, line 159
Traceback: im = get_thumbnail(request.FILES['photo'], '100x100', crop='center', quality=99)
```

Could anyone help me on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use request.FILES['photo'] here because uploaded file can be in memory or somewhere else. Save this file to filesystem first, then use get_thumbnail. For example, you can call it on your objects after it's returned by form.save().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the uploaded file directly then first you will have to get the path of temp memory where it is uploaded.

```
import os
import tempfile

def _file_path(uploaded_file):
    '''  Converts InMemoryUploadedFile to on-disk file so it will have path. '''
    try:
        return uploaded_file.temporary_file_path()
    except AttributeError:
        fileno, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
        temp_file = os.fdopen(fileno,'w+b')
        for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
            temp_file.write(chunk)
        temp_file.close()
        return path
```

Then you can access the uploaded file at path:

```
path = _file_path(request.FILES['photo'])
```